# Scrape Url and use that for LWP Perl

Tags: perl, scrape

Ok so i know how to make an LWP get request with Perl in a loop. But i would like to know if its possible to scrape an Url from a website and automaticly put that in the url to visit in loop also??

```
#!usr/bin/perl

for ($i=0;$i<200;$i++)
{

use strict;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
use warnings;
 my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'USER AGENT');
 my $response = $ua->get("http://example.com");
 print $response->code,' ', $response->message,"\n";

sleep 2;

}
```

So now i would like to scrape an url from a domain and use that for the example.com and also that it scrapes every visit a new url.

Comment: I've written a tutorial about that: http://blogs.perl.org/users/stas/2013/01/web-scraping-with-modern-perl-part-1.html

Answer (score 4):

> i would like to know if its possible to scrape an Url from a website and automaticly put that in the url to visit in loop also??

Yup! That's called a queue, and it can be implemented trivially using `push` and `shift`.

```
 my @to_visit = ( ...initial URLs... );
 while (@to_visit) {
     my $url = shift(@to_visit);
     my $content = ...Download the file...;
     my @extracted = ...Extract the URLs...;
     push @to_visit, @extracted;
 }
```

Of course, you probably want to skip URLs you've already visited.

```
 my %seen;
 my @to_visit = grep !$seen{$_}++, ( ...initial URLs... );
 while (@to_visit) {
     my $url = shift(@to_visit);
     my $content = ...Download the file...;
     my @extracted = ...Extract the URLs...;
     push @to_visit, grep !$seen{$_}++, @extracted;
 }
```

Comment: i know it's pretty stupid but i dont understand how to use that ;(

Comment: Maybe clearer now? Put the initial URL(s) to visit where it says `...initial URLs...`. Put the code to download `$url` where it says `...Download the file...`. Extract the URLs you want to visit where it says `...Extract the URLs...`.